# Отслеживание нажатия двух кнопок одновременно - Java

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Создавая игру на двух игроков столкнулся с такой проблемой - если один игрок нажал на кнопку, то другой уже не сможет, т.е. игроки не могут двигаться одновременно.

```
private class UpDownKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode==40) {
            if(myPanel.secondPlayer.y<400) {
            myPanel.secondPlayer.y = myPanel.secondPlayer.y+5;
            }
        }
        if(keyCode==38) {
            if(myPanel.secondPlayer.y>0) {
                myPanel.secondPlayer.y = myPanel.secondPlayer.y-5;
            }
        }           

        if(keyCode==83) {
            if(myPanel.firstPlayer.y<400) {
            myPanel.firstPlayer.y = myPanel.firstPlayer.y+5;
            }
        }
        if(keyCode==87) {
            if(myPanel.firstPlayer.y>0) {
                myPanel.firstPlayer.y = myPanel.firstPlayer.y-5;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

}
```

Comment: Где кнопки? На одной клавиатуре? На разных джойстиках? Хотя бы в общем контекст обрисовать нужно.

Comment: Да, на одной клавиатуре.

Comment: покажите код который обрабатывает нажатие на кнопку

Comment: Это Android или нет? Android не поддерживает одновременное нажатие двух клавиш

Comment: Нет, это не Андроид. Для винды.